# How to unlink a secondary non-system drive's "Users" folder shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, users

I have a Windows 10 system SSD (C:) and a non-system HD (D:) in two partitions of the disk (total of 3). **D used to be the old system drive before installing Windows 10 on the SSD**, which may explain why it has this folder in the first place.

While trying to merge the two D: partitions using AOMEI partition assistant, I have encountered a problem with the Users folder. On closer inspection I can see a little shortcut icon for All Users folder on D: linking it to C:

[image: Folder structure]

[image: Link to C:]

How can I unlink the two? If I delete something from
`D:\users\All Users\Microsoft`
for example, which is the problematic folder that AOEMI cannot process, it will be deleted from the same location in C: since they are one and the same.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in Command Prompt as administrator. Follow these steps:

- Take ownership of that folder: `Takeown /F "D:\Users\All Users"`
- Grant full permissions to everyone: `Icacls "D:\Users\All Users" /grant Everyone:F`
- Delete the folder: Use `Rd "D:\Users\All Users"` or `Del /F "D:\Users\All Users"`.

This step is alternative. If that folder is quickly created before merging the partitions, then run this command as administrator to create a blank file in that path: `echo.> "D:\Users\All Users"`

Further readings:

- [Takeown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown)
- [Icacls command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)
- [Rd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd)